# Output of program does not make sense

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I don't understand the logic behind this..
I expect this program to output `2` but it outputs `3`
Can you explain the working of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    int a = - -3; 

    printf("a=%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect 2? `- -` is not the prefix decrease operator `--`. In addition, you can't use `--` and `++` on an integer constant such as `3`, because it is not a writeable variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
int a = - -3;
```

this statement there is no `--(decrement operator)` , it is **unary minus** operator, which makes `- -3` as `3(cancelling negation)`. Hence it prints `3`.

Side note, if you think of this

```
int a = --3;
```

as prints `2` then you thinks wrong, as this cause **lvalue error** because `--` applicable on variable not on constant. Correct one is

```
int a = 3;
--a ;/* this is valid,this make a as 2 now */
```

Answer (score 3):

`- -3` is a double and therefore cancelling negation.

It's an expression equal to 3. Apart from `-INT_MIN` which is undefined on a 2's complement system, a double negation is equivalent to the unary plus `+`.

If you had written `--3` then the *maximal munch* rule would have compiled this as an attempt to *decrement* the constant `3`, which is not allowed, and compilation would fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = - -3;
```

is parsed as

```
a = - (-3);
```

so you're negating a negative `3`, giving a positive `3`.

If you were intending to write

```
a = --3;
```

then you would have gotten a compile-time error, as the `--` operator cannot be applied to constant expressions.